# Why is my variable referencing the global scope variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I tried to write a function that finds all possible permutations given an array of numbers. Here is my code.

```
var perm = [];
var usedchar = [];

function findAllPermutations(arr) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var x = arr.splice(i,1)[0];
    usedchar.push(x);

    if (usedchar.length == 3) {
      perm.push(usedchar);
    }

    findAllPermutations(arr);
    usedchar.pop();
    arr.splice(i,0,x);
  }
}

findAllPermutations([1,2,3]);

console.log(perm); //-> [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

I expect to get:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Can someone explain why I'm not getting this answer?

Comment: I can't explain because you never labelled your question with the language you are using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `console.log` is a dead giveaway; but OP, you do need to tag questions appropriately (and indent them correctly, or no-one will bother to look for where your scope is).

Comment: I would assume some flavor of JavaScript, but adding a label also helps people find a question.

Comment: There is no need to terminate a block with a semicolon, it is seen as an empty statement. Not harmful, just useless.

Comment: Apologies, this is my second post! Thanks for the feedback, I'll make sure to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
perm.push(usedchar);
```

needs to be

```
perm.push(usedchar.slice());
```

in order to clone the `usedchar` array, to snapshot it at that moment. Otherwise, you end up with six references to `usedchar` that had all kinds of stuff pushed in and then popped out, ending up empty at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same array that holds your intermediate result as storage for your algorithm and things are getting mixed up. You need to either separate the two or make sure you clone your usedchar array before pushing it into your perm array. Something like this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HQ6q8fo8S0K21cISQKVt

```
  var perm = [];
  var usedchar = [];
  var another = [];

  function findAllPermutations(arr) {


  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var x = arr.splice(i,1)[0];
    usedchar.push(x);

    if (usedchar.length == 3) {
      perm.push(usedchar.slice());
    };

    findAllPermutations(arr);
    usedchar.pop();
    arr.splice(i,0,x);
  };
};

findAllPermutations([1,2,3]);
console.log(perm);
```

Comment: Where will the OP find the *$* function? Why is it necessary?

Comment: You're right, don't need it. That's just from the plunker I used. I'll edit it out.